# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkUpkeep')

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, chainlink-vrf

mockOffChain.js

```
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat")

async function mockKeepers() {
    // const raffle = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle")
    const contractAddress = (await deployments.get("Raffle")).address
    const raffle_contract = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle", contractAddress)
    const raffle = raffle_contract.address
    const checkData = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(""))
    const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
    if (upkeepNeeded) {
        const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep(checkData)
        const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
        const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
        console.log(`Performed upkeep with RequestId: ${requestId}`)
        if (network.config.chainId == 31337) {
            await mockVrf(requestId, raffle)
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No upkeep needed!")
    }
}

async function mockVrf(requestId, raffle) {
    console.log("We on a local network? Ok let's pretend...")
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, raffle.address)
    console.log("Responded!")
    const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
    console.log(`The winner is: ${recentWinner}`)
}

mockKeepers()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

Error

```
yarn hardhat run scripts/mockOffChain.js --network localhost
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ '/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/.bin/hardhat' run scripts/mockOffChain.js --network localhost
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkUpkeep')
    at mockKeepers (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/scripts/mockOffChain.js:49:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I don't understand how to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

You set the variable `raffle` in this line of code:

```
const raffle = raffle_contract.address
```

This will only store the *address* of the contract in `raffle`, not the contracts functions and things like that. As a result, the error tells you that `checkUpkeep` is undefined - it's a function in the Raffle contract (I assume), but the variable is only the address.

otoh, you have stored the contract in a different variable - `raffle_contract`. As a result, I would think you should be able to change this line:

```
const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
```

to:

```
const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle_contract.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
```

and as long as there is a function called `checkUpkeep` in the contract, it should work.